# How to know What/who created a folder

Tags: windows, windows-10

I know this may be a tricky question but on my Windows 11 machine
Some folders are being created every time I boot the system. I delete them and they get created again and all of them are empty.

I disabled all startup programs but folders get created.

Is there anyway/Tool to know how/who/what created a folder?

As the last resort I will disable all services one by one and reboot but this will take forever and may not even help.

Also my antivirus does not report of any virus/malware.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To trace which process is creating these folders, you could use the free
[Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/).

You will need to use the Boot Time Logging option of Process Monitor,
delete these folders, boot, then search within the log for one of the
newly-created folder. This will identify the process that created it.

Be warned that Boot Time Logging slows down very noticeably the boot process,
so ensure it is not still turned on for your next boot.

Reference:
[How To Enable System Boot Time Logging using Process Monitor Tool](https://www.msigeek.com/6231/how-to-enable-system-boot-time-logging-using-process-monitor-tool).

Comment: Very promising. I will test it!

Comment: Cannot see "Enable boot Logging? under options menu . I'm using v16.43. Hopefully this is not removed.

Comment: What version you are using?

Comment: I downloaded version 16 but still do not see that option.

Comment: OK you are referring to Process Monitor not Process Explorer. clearly a typo. . Please edit/correct your answer and I will Accept it. Thanks for letting me know about these wonderful tools!

Comment: Done, sorry for the error.

Answer (score 3):

By default, whoever creates the item (file, folder, etc) becomes the owner. You can check the owner by

1. Right-click the folder and click **Properties**. Under the **Security** tab, click **Advanced** and the owner will be displayed here, near the top. The general tab will also show the Creation date (but this can be changed so not useful in the case of something malicious)
2. Open a PowerShell terminal and type the following command, substituting your folder for the <FolderPath>:
   `Get-ACL <FolderPath> | Select-Object Owner`

As for the folders themselves, there are many legitimate processes which cause random folders to be created. Hidden folders in the root of the C: drive, for example, are created by the Windows Updte process (`$Windows.~WS` or similar) as well as installers for a lot of standard software (NVidia, Intel, to name a couple).

Comment: The owner is likely 'System', 'Trusted_installer' or something else... That doesn't narrow it down much I'm afraid.

Comment: Perfect, it shows the logged in user on our network drive, many thanks!